# Arrays en javascript

Tags: javascript, array

tengo un problema que no puedo resolver.
Supongamos que tengo tres arrays.

Como genero un solo array  y que en cada objeto dentro del array nuevo estén todos los valores. Es decir crear un array de objetos y que los objetos dentro de ese array contenga toda la data

````
personas = [
      {id: 1, nombre: Raul, dni:11125447, }
      {id: 2, nombre: Pablo, dni:22478124, }
      {id: 3, nombre: Juan, dni:33125963, }
   ]
   
   actividad= [
       {id: 1, name: ganaderia}
       {id:2, name: agricultura}
       {id:3, name: Granja}
   
   ]
   
   campos = [
      {perosnaId: 1,actividadId:1, tamañoCampo: 1200, año: 2019 }
      {perosnaId: 2,actividadId:2, tamañoCampo: 1400, año: 2018}
      {perosnaId: 3,actividadId:2, tamañoCampo: 1800, año: 2017}
      {perosnaId: 4,actividadId:3, tamañoCampo: 1000, año: 2000}
      {perosnaId: 1,actividadId:3, tamañoCampo: 1500, año: 2015}
   ]```

Como genero un solo array  y que en cada objeto dentro del array nuevo estén todos los valores. Es decir crear un array de objetos y que los objetos dentro de ese array contenga toda la data
````

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo esperado?

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante agregar lo que trataste por favor, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Ejemplo [{nombre:Raul, actividad:ganaderia, tamañoCampo:1200, año:2019}]

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar lo que has intentado al momento? Recuerda que es recomendable incluir un [mcve] e indicar los errores que obtienes sobre el mismo ya que con el código que presentas ahora mismo no se puede replicar el problema (que por cierto no se menciona).